# Again mysql "count distinct"

Tags: mysql, count

I have a strange problem with mysql count. When I execute

```
   SELECT a.inc AS inc,
       a.cls AS cls,
       a.ord AS ord,
       a.fam AS fam,
       a.subfam AS subfam,
       a.gen AS gen,
       aspec AS spec,
       asubspec AS subspec
    FROM a
    WHERE (ainc = 11)
```

I obtain:

[image]

and that's ok, because I have 2 records.

When I execute

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.inc) AS inc,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.cls) AS cls,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.ord) AS ord,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.fam) AS fam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT asubfam) AS subfam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.gen) AS gen,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.spec) AS spec,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.subspec) AS subspec
    FROM a
    WHERE (a.inc = 11)
    GROUP BY a.inc
```

I obtain

[image]

and that's odd because as you see `gen, spec and subspec` have 0 value on one row.
I know that `count distinct` doesn't count zero values. I want to count all value != 0 and after count distinct I want to get

```
`1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |`
```

I also try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.inc) AS inc,
       SUM(if(a.cls <> 0, 1, 0)) AS cls,
       SUM(if(a.ord <> 0, 1, 0)) AS ord,
       SUM(if(a.fam <> 0, 1, 0)) AS fam,
       SUM(if(a.subfam <> 0, 1, 0)) AS subfam,
       SUM(if(a.gen <> 0, 1, 0)) AS gen,
       SUM(if(a.spec <> 0, 1, 0)) AS spec,
       SUM(if(a.subspec <> 0, 1, 0)) AS subspec
  FROM a
GROUP BY a.inc
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.inc) AS inc,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.cls <> 0, 1, 0)) AS cls,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.ord <> 0, 1, 0)) AS ord,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.fam <> 0, 1, 0)) AS fam,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.subfam <> 0, 1, 0)) AS subfam,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.gen <> 0, 1, 0)) AS gen,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.spec <> 0, 1, 0)) AS spec,
           SUM(DISTINCT if(a.subspec <> 0, 1, 0)) AS subspec
FROM a
GROUP BY a.inc
```

but it's not working because in first approach doesn't make distinct and sum all duplicate values greater than 0; and in second case it give just 1 and 0 .
So, can someone help me with that? Thank you in advance. Leo

Comment: What makes you think DISTINCT doesn't count 0 values? It doesn't count _NULL_ values, but NULL is not the same as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that count distinct doesn't count zero values.

I don't know where you got that idea, but it is not correct. Perhaps you are thinking of NULL values? One way to get the results you desire is to treat the 0s as NULL in your distinct count.

Try something like this (I also removed the group by, which was not helping):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.inc = 0 then null else a.inc end) AS inc,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.cls = 0 then null else a.cls end) AS cls,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.ord = 0 then null else a.ord end) AS ord,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.fam = 0 then null else a.fam end) AS fam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.subfam = 0 then null else a.subfam end) AS subfam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.gen = 0 then null else a.gen end) AS gen,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.spec = 0 then null else a.spec end) AS spec,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when a.subspec = 0 then null else a.subspec end) AS subspec
    FROM a
    WHERE (a.inc = 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.inc) AS inc,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.cls, 0)) AS cls,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.ord, 0)) AS ord,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.fam, 0)) AS fam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.subfam, 0)) AS subfam,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.gen, 0)) AS gen,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.spec, 0)) AS spec,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(a.subspec, 0)) AS subspec
FROM a
```

Comment: NULLIF is a MySQL function equivalent to the CASE construct in Ike Walter's answer.

Comment: My God this it's quite elegant! Thank you! :)